# JQuery and Css animtaion not working on IE

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a problem regarding my webpage, I checked on all other browsers and it work but the only problem is IE. is doesn't work on IE. I have an animtaion for opacity.

on IE it doesn't animate anything

here is my code:

## Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.hideme').css('display', 'none');

        /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
        $('#activate').click(function() {
            $('.hideme').css('pointer-events', 'all');
            /* Check the location of each desired element */
            $('.hideme').each(function(i) {

                var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
                if (bottom_of_window => bottom_of_object) {
                    $(this).animate({
                        'opacity': '1',
                        ' -moz-opacity': '1',
                        ' -khtml-opacity': '1',
                        'transition': 'all .3s linear',
                    }, 1500);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

## HTML/PHP

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: which version of IE you are using ?

Comment: @RajenderVerma ie11

Comment: Shouldn't `=>` in `bottom_of_window => bottom_of_object` be `>=`?

Comment: Thats it! Thank mate! it worked like a miracle. thanks for saving me. @NikhilAggarwal

Comment: @セアンデエ - Glad to help you mate!